# Converting double to unsigned char?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a matrix of (doubles) into an unsigned char so I can then write to a .pmg file... But it isn't working.

```
void writePNG(vector<double>& matrix)
{
vector<unsigned char> image;
ofstream myfile;

myfile.open("newFile.txt", ios::out); // writing to .txt file for now for testing.

if(!myfile.is_open())
{
    cout << "Cannot open file";
}
for(int i=0; (i < 512*512); i++)
{
    image[i] = (unsigned char) matrix[i];
}

myfile.close();
}
```

It won't convert the data. Any ideas?? Thanks :)

Comment: What exactly is the error? Is there a compiler error? Is the file empty (which is definitely the case, because you don't write anything)? Is there any runtime error?

Comment: Change the declaration to `vector<unsigned char> image(512*512);`.

Comment: What's the error you're seeing then? What are the ranges of the values in the matrix-vector? E.g. if -1...1 then you need to scale the values first.

Comment: The way the code is written right now, you store the `unsigned char` elements in a vector, but there is nothing in the code that actually writes the vector to a file. It just opens the file and later closes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **bug**: You are creating a vector of size 0, and then writing to its non-existent elements.
- **bug**: You never write the data to a file
- *style*: You close the file needlessly. It will be closed when the `fstream` object goes out of scope
- *style*: You copy the data in a loop. Using `vector::vector` displays your intent more clearly.
- *potential bug*: You create an output vector of 512x512, regardless of the size of the input vector.
- *[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)* Your testcase is incomplete.

Try this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void writePNG(const std::vector<double>& matrix)
{
  std::ofstream myfile("newFile.txt", std::ios::out); 

  if(!myfile.is_open())
  {
    std::cout << "Cannot open file";
  }
  std::vector<unsigned char> image (matrix.begin(), matrix.end());
  myfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&image[0]), image.size());
}

int main () {
  writePNG({
    72, 101, 108.1, 108.2,
    111, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x77,
    0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c,
    100.3,  10.4});
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you use static_cast<char*>()` instead of the `reinterpret_cast<>`?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `image` using the default constructor of `vector`, which initializes the vector as empty (containing no elements).  The subscript notation (`image[i]`) does not create an element, only assigns to an already exising one.

You have (at least) two ways to fix it:

- declare `image` using the ctor of `vector` that allocates the necessary size: `vector<unsigned char> image(512*512)` -- this will populate the vector with 512*512 elements of default value (0 for `unsigned char`)
- add the elements one-by-one using the `push_back` method: `image.push_back((unsigned char) matrix[i]);`

You also will have to write the contents of `image` to `myfile` eventually.

Note: it is a good habit to use `static_cast<unsigned char>(...)` instead of the C-style `(unsigned char) ...` as the former can find errors that the latter will not flag; this is not an issue in this particular case, though

Answer (score 0):

You image vector has zero size - you would have to at least do a push_back to add an element.  Also, the size of a double is not the same size of a char so you are going to lose information.